# How do I handle external redirects to a client side react app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I'm building a web app that uses the True Layer open banking API. The app has a React front end using react router and an Express and Nodejs backend. Currently I am using the react `build` script to serve the static files:

```
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.static('../client/build'));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/')});
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on port: ", PORT);
});

// The API routes are imported below
```

This solution works well but when the user is redirected to True Layer's authentication page an OAuth code is generated and passed back to a route on the client as a url query. The issue is that when True Layer redirect the user back to my app the url is interpreted by the server and not the react router/browser so it returns `cannot GET /myAccounts`. I've looked into using server side rendering for the React client with a library like Next.js but I wanted to know if there was a way to do it without having to significantly refactor my code.

My React Router setup:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Route name="Landing" path="/" exact component={Login} />
                <Route name="Login" path="/login" exact component={Login} />
                <Route name="MyAccounts" path="/myAccounts" exact component={Home} />
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

The `/myAccounts` route renders the `Home` component/page where the `code` parameter is extracted: `qs.parse(props.location.search)['?code']`, and sent to my server to complete the OAuth process.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the rest of your routes? You have an `app.get('*', ...)`, which should catch all GET requests, so something doesn't add up.

Comment: @Jacob The rest of the routes are just an assortment of GET and POST routes that query external API's or process data. The problem is that when True Layer's auth page redirects the user back to my app at `/myAccounts?code=478hds...` the server acts as if it was a request to one of it's routes,  but the request is meant for the React DOM router's `/myAccounts` route where the `code` parameter is extracted: `qs.parse(props.location.search)['?code']` and sent back to my server to complete the OAuth process. Sorry if that was unclear in my original question I'll edit it now.

Comment: You can't avoid a redirect from a separate site hitting your server, if that's what you're after. All you can really do is make sure your server serves up the page on these requests. If this "True Layer" login page is a separate site, your original document will have unloaded.

Comment: @Jacob Yeah, that makes sense, I kind of thought that would be the case but hoped that there would some sort of trick I could use to keep the page loaded/not require SSR. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 2):

> The issue is that when True Layer redirect the user back to my app the url is interpreted by the server and not the react router/browser so it returns cannot GET /myAccounts

What happens is:
The path `/myAccounts` is the internal path of your React SPA which displays the internal SPA page rendered by `MyAccounts` component. The webserver is not aware of this page and returns "cannot GET /myAccounts". This webserver behaviour is incorrect not because the webserver doesn't support True Layer/OAuth but rather because the webserver doesn't support SPA correctly.

What should happen:
The webserver should support SPA by implementing the fallback behaviour which simply means the server redirects requests for unknown pages to the SPA landing page. For example, this behaviour is enabled in webpack-dev-server using the [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback) which exists specifically to support SPAs.

The fallback behavior is required for any SPA because the user can see the path to any internal page in the navigation bar and can either retype it manually and press Enter or refresh the browser. In both cases the webserver gets hit with a request for the internal SPA page it is not aware of and responding with 404 error doesn't look good for the user.

Once you implement fallback in Express, you can add a piece of data to the Request being redirected to the landing page. So that your `Landing` component will see this optional piece and redirect internally (webserver won't know) to `MyAccounts` component.

Comment: Thanks! I saw a solution like that but it required using a webpack setup to implement, which my client SPA isn't configured with atm. I found [This npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-history-api-fallback) that I thought would do it but it seems to just be a catch all route that serves the `index.html` and that sends me into a loop of failed redirects back to the landing page. I can't seem to find any way of implementing fallback in Express. I'm not completely opposed to implementing webpack but if there is a way of doing it using Express that would be much preferred.

Comment: I wrote a boilerplate [Crisp React](https://winwiz1.github.io/crisp-react/), it implements fallbacks in both webpack-dev-server and in [Express](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/blob/master/server/src/srv/server.ts). For the latter there is a [test case](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/blob/master/server/src/test/server.test.ts) to test the fallback redirects. Even though it's written in TypeScript, I hope you you will find the project useful. There is an [article](https://hackernoon.com/full-stack-react-typescript-express-project-with-advanced-features-ts4m308w) about it.

Comment: That looks great thank you I tried to pick out just the Express fallback and wrote [this](https://gist.github.com/JesseDavda/44ecebd0bd0aede629b68001d371dd29). This causes an infinite redirect loop, currently I just check if the url is `/myAccounts` or `/login` and then I'm just serving the full built client at it's entry point where it checks for a JWT and then if one is found tries to redirect to `/myAccounts` and that loops back to `/` - this also causes my normal REST API routes to return the html for the built client. A bit stuck here :/

Answer (score 0):

P.S.
To cater for login the logic needs to be modified.
The preferred (and more logically simple/clear) option in this case is to have 2 SPAs: on for the login, another for the rest of the application. But I understand it would mean more changes to the existing app and that is why you prefer to change Express side only. This can be done but the logic gets more complex.

Client side
In your only entrypoint for the only SPA you can have:

```js
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  <Route path="/myaccount" component={either Login or maybe MyAccount} />
  <Route component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

The `Home` component should verify the client is logged in (for example by checking the cookie set by Express or external cloud server after successful login) and if not redirect internally (`history.push`) to `/login`.   In the same manner `Login` component should check if the client has been authenticated and if so redirect internally to`'/'` e.g. to `Home` component.

Express side logic

- `/` - serve `index.html` (the only .html file produced by React build since you have one SPA) which eventually goes to Router which in turn will render `Home` component due to the 1st `<Route>`
- `/index` – serve `index.html`. Router will render `Home` component due to the 4th `<Route>`.
- `/login` – serve `index.html`.  This is a fallback (for example already logged in user can manually type this path).  Router will render `Login` component due to the 2nd `<Route>`
- `/myaccount` – serve `index.html`. The Router will render `Login` component due to the 3rd `<Route>`. The component should be able to get the `?code=123bac...`
- unknown page that doesn't look malicious. It's probably some internal path to some internal page of your SPA retyped by a user. Fallback to '/' to show `Home` component.